# How to fetch data from an array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, fetch

How to fetch data from an array in PHP.

I know how to use `array_filter` or `array_search`, but which is do not know is that how can i search something that is on present on the array value but in a different way.

For make it more clear --

```
Suppose i am looking for **Samsung Galaxy S** from my array $data,
but it will return an empty array, because there is not exact match for that data type.
```

But the **"Samsung Galaxy S"** is available in the array in **array value 1, 2 and 4**

So How can i fetch "Samsung Galaxy S" from this array !!

Anyone knows how to solve this problem !!!

```
$data =
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => Samsung GT-N7100 Galaxy Note II 16GB
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => Samsung GT-i9100 Galaxy S II
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [name] => Samsung GT-i9300 Galaxy S III 16GB
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [name] => Apple iPhone 5 16GB
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [name] => Samsung GT-P5110 Galaxy S 4 10.1 16GB
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [name] => Samsung UE46ES6715
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [name] => Samsung 830 Series MZ-7PC128 128GB
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [name] => Samsung GT-N8000 Galaxy Note 10.1 16GB
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [name] => Samsung 830 Series MZ-7PC256 256GB
        )

    [9] => Array
        (
            [name] => Samsung UE46ES6715
        )

    [10] => Array
        (
            [name] => Samsung GT-2423 Galaxy Tab 4 10.1 16GB
        )
```

Comment: Search for and learn about regular expressions

Comment: @Clive can u give me an example !

Comment: Better to learn it yourself, then you don't need to keep getting other people to do it. Do some tutorials, try some things, and if you get stuck at a specific point, ask a question about it here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can loop the array and use a `regex` with [positive lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to check if the model exists:

```
foreach($models as $key => $model) {
    if (preg_match('/Samsung(?=.*?Galaxy S)/i', $model)) {
        echo $model;
    }
}
```

### **Regex Explanation**

```
Samsung(?=.*?Galaxy S)

Options: Case insensitive; Exact spacing; Dot doesn’t match line breaks; ^$ don’t match at line breaks; Greedy quantifiers

Match the character string “Samsung” literally «Samsung»
Assert that the regex below can be matched, starting at this position (positive lookahead) «(?=.*?Galaxy S)»
   Match any single character that is NOT a line break character «.*?»
      Between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy) «*?»
   Match the character string “Galaxy S” literally «Galaxy S»
```

---

**REGEX DEMO:**

https://regex101.com/r/oL0vO1/1

---

**PHP DEMO:**

http://ideone.com/ievsN2

Comment: thanks a lot, thanks a lot for your great answer and explaining it so clearly ... You are awesome

Comment: You're very welcome @ChristoferHansen   :) If my answer helped you, please consider accepting it as the correct answer by clicking the check mark in the middle of the vote arrows, tks !

Comment: i have already done that in the beganing, as soon as i read your answer

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with `array_filter` and `preg_match` . I did a function `my_array_search` for your problem :

I replace all the space (`/\s+/`) with `.*` in `'Samsung Galaxy S'` to make a regex pattern and then use `array_filter` with `preg_match`

```
$data =array('Samsung GT-N7100 Galaxy Note II 16GB','Samsung GT-i9100 Galaxy S II','Samsung GT-i9300 Galaxy S III 16GB','Apple iPhone 5 16GB','Samsung GT-P5110 Galaxy S 4 10.1 16GB','Samsung UE46ES6715','Samsung 830 Series MZ-7PC128 128GB','Samsung GT-N8000 Galaxy Note 10.1 16GB','Samsung 830 Series MZ-7PC256 256GB','Samsung UE46ES6715','Samsung GT-2423 Galaxy Tab 4 10.1 16GB');
print_r($data);

function my_array_search($array, $string)
{
    $pattern = preg_replace ('/\s+/',' .*',preg_quote($string));
    return array_filter($array, 
    function ($value) use($pattern) {
        return preg_match('/'.$pattern.'/',$value ) == 1;
    });
}

print_r(my_array_search($data,'Samsung Galaxy S'));
```

result

```
Array
(
    [0] => Samsung GT-N7100 Galaxy Note II 16GB
    [1] => Samsung GT-i9100 Galaxy S II
    [2] => Samsung GT-i9300 Galaxy S III 16GB
    [3] => Apple iPhone 5 16GB
    [4] => Samsung GT-P5110 Galaxy S 4 10.1 16GB
    [5] => Samsung UE46ES6715
    [6] => Samsung 830 Series MZ-7PC128 128GB
    [7] => Samsung GT-N8000 Galaxy Note 10.1 16GB
    [8] => Samsung 830 Series MZ-7PC256 256GB
    [9] => Samsung UE46ES6715
    [10] => Samsung GT-2423 Galaxy Tab 4 10.1 16GB
)
Array
(
    [1] => Samsung GT-i9100 Galaxy S II
    [2] => Samsung GT-i9300 Galaxy S III 16GB
    [4] => Samsung GT-P5110 Galaxy S 4 10.1 16GB
)
```

Comment: Give some explanation please, not only code. [How to answer.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: Please look well to the array and to your regex, does it match ? no.

Comment: It match 1,2,4 like he expected in his question